# Import command in DB2

Tags: import, db2

In DB2, I have one table:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( test_id INTEGER NULL, test_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, test_test VARCHAR(255))
```

Now I want to import data into this table and used the command

```
IMPORT from '/home/test.txt' of del MODIFIED BY LOBSINFILE INSERT INTO test
```

It works fine if the `test.txt` file contains the below content.

```
\N, "aaaaaaa", "aaaaaaa"
\N, "bbbbbbb", "bbbbbbb"
```

But if the text file contains below data, it inserts multiple records.

```
\N, "<section>\
               <id root=\"84f194ae-f573-4249-8368-e38c74891965\"/>\
               <code code=\"34071-1\" codeSystem=\"2.16.840.1.113883.6.1\" displayName=\"WARNINGS SECTION\"/>\
               <title>Warnings</title>\
               <text>\
                  <paragraph>For external use only, do not use in the eye area.<br/>\
                  </paragraph>\
               </text>\
               <effectiveTime value=\"20100225\"/>\
            </section>","aaaaaaa"
\N, 'bbbbbbb', 'bbbbbb'
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the quotes in your data with another quote like this:

```
\N, "<section>\
               <id root=""84f194ae-f573-4249-8368-e38c74891965""/>\
               <code code=""34071-1"" codeSystem=""2.16.840.1.113883.6.1"" displayName=""WARNINGS SECTION""/>\
           <title>Warnings</title>\
           <text>\
              <paragraph>For external use only, do not use in the eye area.<br/>\
              </paragraph>\
           </text>\
           <effectiveTime value=""20100225""/>\
        </section>","aaaaaaa"
```

Then use this import syntax:

```
IMPORT from '/home/test.txt' of del MODIFIED BY DELPRIORITYCHAR XMLPARSE PRESERVE WHITESPACE INSERT INTO test
```

Also, varchar(255) isn't big enough for your example.

Comment: Also note that DB2 does not see '\' as a line continuation character.     DELPRIORITYCHAR is the key to this answer.  If you added the '\' in the text to try and get IMPORT to work, you can safely remove these extra characters.

Comment: Thank You so much. It works well. I have given maximum size to insert the data as CLOB(2G). BUt some of the data will be truncated bcos of space. Can I able to improve the size of CLOB greater than 2G?

Answer (score 0):

From the DB2 reference guide: **"Note: XML data cannot be stored directly in the base table row in delimited files. It must be placed in separate files and referenced using an XDS."**

You cannot import XML data just like that (or anything that implies new lines - this applies to [LOBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_business#Computer_applications) as well). Instead, what you need to specify in the column is the XML file name, and the import file type will be `DEL XML` instead of `DEL`.

Check *[Exporting XML data](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/c0024102.htm)* for more clarifications.